# How to cancel paypal recurring subscription using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I am unable to cancel the subscription.How to cancel paypal recurring subscription using asp.net. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ManageRecurringPaymentProfileStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/) API call to do this.

Comment: how to use  ManageRecurringPaymentProfileStatus API?

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in yor account.
2. click setting
3. Tap Payment on the list option, and choose Manage pre-approved payments

Read more: [How to cancel recurring paypal](http://adtavita.com/cancel-recurring-payment-paypal/)

Comment: The question asks how to do it with ASP.NET, which means that the OP wants to do it programmatically, and not manually using the web interface.